# MySQL Resource id #

Tags: php, mysql, string

I request a password from a remote server, store in a database table and recover it for use in several URL requests, and am able to retrieve xml data which I can then display on my pages.

This seems to work fine, except in addition to the xml data, the code also seems to output strings that looks like this:

```
Resource id #[random number]
```

Does anyone know what this might be due to?

My code to recover the password from the db looks like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_table WHERE id=1") 
or die(mysql_error());  

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$my_info =  $row['id_string'];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats a string conversion of a php resource like your db handle, result from a db query, or a file handle (retunred from fopen). Somewhere you are doing something like

```
echo $result;
```

as opposed to

```
echo $my_info;
```

Answer (score 3):

That's the string that results when echoing the, uh, result. The solution is to stop echoing it.

Answer (score 2):

if you're getting resource id#, it means that you echo $result.

And on another note:
if you need only one value, I'd suggest using the following:

```
$id_string = mysql_result($result, 0, 'id_string');
```