# Curl Error - Resource id #88

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I am trying to execute the following curl code:

```
$URL = "https://app.getresponse.com/add_subscriber.htm";
$post_data = "name=ABC&email=myemail@gmail.com&campaign_token=poga1&start_day=0&";


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Running this curl gives: Resource id #88

Any clues?

Comment: Thank you for the code; I don't think it's a cUrl error, but [a PHP one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592067/mysql-resource-id). Does that help you? You might have `echo "$ch";` at the end of your script.

Comment: have you tried something like `$result = curl_exec($ch);` and then do `echo $result;`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Curl returning 'Resource id #2 ' as response why?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26066015)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $URL = "https://app.getresponse.com/add_subscriber.htm";
    $post_data = "name=ABC&email=myemail@gmail.com&campaign_token=poga1&start_day=0&";   

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response);
```

The issue was you have not assign response of curl execution